# Which database should I use for a local application?

Tags: sqlite

I am programming a standalone application which needs a local database storage.

I have read about SQLite and it seems like it could perfectly fit my needs.

Nonetheless someone told me that SQLite is going to be discontinued. Is that true ? If so, what technology should I use instead ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lts.html) says:

> The intent of the developers is to support SQLite through the year 2050.

Answer (score 1):

The developers are working on [a new major version](https://sqlite.org/src4/home), actually. Maybe whoever told you that heard about it and got confused thinking this means work on SQLite 3 is stopped (it isn't). But even if it were discontinued, the current version isn't going to disappear or stop working.